Problem with the height of a container in tailwind remix
I'm trying to make a remix dashboard with tailwind and when it comes to placing several charts inside a container with a maximum height, it overflows below creating a blank space...
[Error]
[Error]
import { Outlet } from '@remix-run/react'
import Navbar from '../components/navbar'
import { json } from "@remix-run/node"
import { useLoaderData } from "@remix-run/react"
import { db } from "../services/index.js"


export async function loader(){
  const test_client = await db.cliente.findMany()
  return test_client;
};

export default function Dashboard() {
  const userData = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();
  console.log(userData)
  return (
    <div className="rounded-md overflow-y-auto row-spam">
        <div className="grid grid-rows-[1fr,auto] gap-x-[20px] p-8 sm:grid-cols-[auto,1fr] max-h-screen">
            <nav className="border bg-white space-y-8 shadow-lg rounded-md row-span-3 order-last sm:order-first">
              <Navbar/>
            </nav> 
            <main className='overflow-y-auto h-full'>
              <Outlet/>
            </main>

        </div>
    </div>
  )
}


import type { MetaFunction } from '@remix-run/node'
import AreaChart from '~/components/areachart'
import ColumnChart from '~/components/columnchart'
import LineChart from '~/components/linechart'
import PieChart from '~/components/piechart'
import DonutChart from '~/components/donutchart'
import RadialChart from '~/components/radialchart'
import { json } from "@remix-run/node"
import { useLoaderData } from "@remix-run/react"

export const meta: MetaFunction = () => {
  return [
    { title: 'Dashboard' },
    { name: 'description', content: 'This is the content for dashboard index' }
  ]
}

export async function loader(){
    return json({
        "dato1": "tessst",
        "dato2": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/79.jpg",
    });
};

export default function DashboardIndex () {
  const tags = [
    <LineChart key='line'/>,
    <AreaChart key='area'/>,
    <ColumnChart key='column'/>,
    <PieChart key ='pie'/>,
    <DonutChart key='donut'/>,
    <RadialChart key='radial'/>
  ]
  const userData = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();
  console.log(userData)
  return (
    <div className='h-28'>
    <div className="flex flex-wrap items-center justify-center">
        {tags.map((tag, index) => (
            <div key={index} className={'m-2'}>
                {tag}
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
    </div>

  )
}


I have tried several times changing the heights with screen, with full, with auto, and none of the ways work for me
